# ID of table with multiple data types

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a small issue, if I were to have a table called, for example, `emails` that contains *emails* and *user information*, how can each email have multiple questions and answers? Do I create a second table with secret questions and answers and use `Foreign key`to associate them to each email? If so, do I associate them to each `email_name` or `id`?

If it's the latter, when inserting them, would I have to first insert the email and then, in the `secret table`, insert `email_name`/`id` again?

Example:

```
+----+------------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+
| id |    email_name    | password |    date    |  ph_num  |    secret_question    | secret_answer |
+----+------------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+
|  1 | jsmith@gmail.com |   123456 | 20.03.2013 | 56546513 | Name of first pet?    | Rex           |
|    |                  |          |            |          | Mother's maiden name? | Anna          |
|  2 | asmith@gmail.com |  6021512 | 02.06.2015 | 23169584 | Real name?            | Shaquesha     |
|    |                  |          |            |          | First car?            | BMW           |
|  3 | rsmith@gmail.com |   123564 | 30.07.2008 | 13546849 | Secret number?        | 90321         |
+----+------------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: You'd follow the standard rules of a normalised design. You might, in addition, encrypt the answers in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to create a separate table for questions and answers. And use `primary key` of `emailid` table as `foreign key` in `questions` table.

Use `id` as `primary key` and `foreign key` in `emailid` and `questions` table respectively as `id` is number and will be storing less memory compare to `emailid` column.

Comment: Sounds pretty nice. Thank you kindly.